# ContentType appears to be a "Computed" field and not "Choice" field through API - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We are trying to use the ListFieldIterator control to display the edit form of a list item including the content type. When viewing the list item in edit mode in the UI, the content type shows up as a dropdown with the list of content types but when going through the listfielditerator, the "content type" field shows up as a computed field but not as a "choice" field.

When looking at this field through SharePoint manager, the field shows up as a Choice but not as a dropdown but in SP2007, the content type field shows up as a "Choice" field. Is there any way to resolve this issue? How does the content type appear as a dropdown if internally, it is a choice field in SP2010?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Interesting behavior. Could you show the code you are using to create the field? You know that there are several display choices you can make for the choice field? i.e. Drop-Down, Check-Boxes, Default value= choice or calculated value?

Answer (score 0):

A regular Edit Form does not render the Content Type through the [ListFieldIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator.aspx) control, but through the [ChangeContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.changecontenttype.aspx) control. I'm surprised the ListFieldIterator is displaying the Content Type field. It should be filtered out by [IsFieldExcluded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator.isfieldexcluded.aspx).

```
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate id="ListForm" runat="server">
    <Template>
        <span id='part1'>
            <SharePoint:InformationBar runat="server"/>
            <div id="listFormToolBarTop">
            <wssuc:ToolBar CssClass="ms-formtoolbar" id="toolBarTbltop" RightButtonSeparator="&amp;#160;" runat="server">
                    <Template_RightButtons>
                        <SharePoint:NextPageButton runat="server"/>
                        <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server"/>
                        <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server"/>
                    </Template_RightButtons>
            </wssuc:ToolBar>
            </div>
            <SharePoint:FormToolBar runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:ItemValidationFailedMessage runat="server"/>
            <table class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <SharePoint:ChangeContentType runat="server"/> <!-- ChangeContentType -->
            <SharePoint:FolderFormFields runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:ListFieldIterator runat="server"/> <!-- ListFieldIterator -->
            <SharePoint:ApprovalStatus runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:FormComponent TemplateName="AttachmentRows" runat="server"/>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tr><td class="ms-formline"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='1' height='1' alt="" /></td></tr></table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="padding-top: 7px"><tr><td width="100%">
            <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:ParentInformationField runat="server"/>
            <SharePoint:InitContentType runat="server"/>
            <wssuc:ToolBar CssClass="ms-formtoolbar" id="toolBarTbl" RightButtonSeparator="&amp;#160;" runat="server">
                    <Template_Buttons>
                        <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo runat="server"/>
                    </Template_Buttons>
                    <Template_RightButtons>
                        <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server"/>
                        <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server"/>
                    </Template_RightButtons>
            </wssuc:ToolBar>
            </td></tr></table>
        </span>
        <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server"/>
    </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```